# Can nginx mask URIs when serving static files?

Tags: nginx

Is this possible in Nginx:

when the user queries `www.example.com/a/b/c`, nginx returns a static file mapped to `/home/www/example/a/b/c.html`?

If so, how should I structure the location section of the nginx config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's very possible, e.g. like so:

```
server {
  root /home/www/example;

  location  / {
    try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/;
  } 
}
```

that would for each request check if:

1. there's a matching file if you tack on .html
2. if not check if there's an exact filename match
3. if not check if there's a directory with that name (in which case either the index, autoindex, or an error will be returned depending on the rest of your config)

Comment: Assuming the first check matches none at all. 
If you fall through to step 2 the extra performance impact is 1 failed request check for $uri.html (and so on)